# free memory if pointer redirects

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free

I've some trouble understanding how to free my memory correctly in following codesnippet:

```
char *func(char* s){

   /* do something with s */


   // pass s to function, create new string, return this string
   s = function_allocating_mem(s);

   // pass s to function, create new string, return this string
   s = other_function_allocation_mem(s);
   /* do other stuff again */

   return s;
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "somestring";
    str = func(str);
}
```

Now I allocated different sizes of memory two times. But if I get it right, I just change the pointer address and never free the memory.

I don't really know, what to google to find an example

Is that correct and how would I change it?

**EDIT:**
I removed the second parameter of the function. It was not necessary and confusing.

Comment: `str = func(str);` doesn't make sense as per your function declaration.

Comment: You need to decide if the pointer passed needs to always be dynamically allocated (which is not the case in your example) or you will need to pass in some indicator of whether or not the pointer is to dynamic memory. Also, if you are going to be freeing the pointer passed in (ie., the function takes ownership of the pointer) then you can't trash it before you free it.

Comment: Do `function_allocating_mem` and `other_function_allocation_mem` just allocate new memory or do they also call `free(s)`?

Comment: By declaring `char str[] = "..."`, you have a label `str` which the compiler replaces with a constant value (address). You cannot change this value after you've declared this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate memory from the heap in your program, you have to have a clear understanding of:

1. Where memory from heap is allocated in your program.
2. How the ownership of heap allocated memory is transferred from one function to the next, and
3. Where it is deallocated before the program ends.

In your case, assuming `function_allocating_mem` and `other_function_allocation_mem` don't call `free` on the input argument, you have to make sure that the memory allocated in those functions is deallocated in either `fun` or `main`.

```
char *func(char* s, const char* os){
   char* s1 = NULL;
   char* s2 = NULL;
   /* do something with s and os */


   // pass s to function, create new string, return this string
   s1 = function_allocating_mem(s);

   // pass s to function, create new string, return this string
   s2 = other_function_allocation_mem(s1);

   /* do other stuff again */

   // Deallocate memory that was allocated by function_allocating_mem().
   free(s1);


   // Memmory allocated by other_function_allocation_mem is returned to the 
   // calling function.
   return s2;
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "somestring";

    // This is not legal anyway.
    // str = func(str, "some other string");

    char* s = fun(str);

    // Use s ...

    // Before returning from this function, deallocate memory
    // that was allocated in the call to fun().
    free(s);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I get, why your code is working, but what if I don't want to use another pointer, but instead overwrite the existing one?

Comment: @Poehli, you can use any variable to store the pointers as long as you are not losing track of allocated memory that needs to be deallocated.

Comment: Okay, but I still need to use another 8-Bit for a second pointer. But you answered my original question best. +1

Answer (score 1):

In code You've provided, correct way to free memory would be:

```
char *s2;
s2 = other_function_allocation_mem(s);
free( s );
s = s2;
...
free( s );
return ns;
```

Comment: Think about what `other_function_allocation_mem(s)` is getting for `s` after that previous `free(s)` call.

Comment: @WhozCraig, true, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

***So many problems.***

<strike>1. You declared that `func` takes two parameters.  Then you only called it with one param.</strike>
 <strike>2. You declared that `func` returns a `char*`, then you try to assign that to a `char[]`.
Arrays and pointers are related, but they are not interchangable.</strike>
 <strike>3. In `func`, you never use param `os`.</strike>
 4. You return variable `ns`.  It was never declared.

Comment: Yes I know, updated question and ignore `char[]` `char*` conversions for the sake of the example ;)